# Drupals clean-urls (.htaccess) breaks with mass vhost

Tags: .htaccess

Apache has a nifty [mass vhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html) feature. Problem is, when I use this to reach my site, clean-urls stop working. Is there a way to combine this with clean urls?

```
<Directory /var/www/localhost/htdocs>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  AllowOverride
</Directory>
UseCanonicalName Off
LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
CustomLog /tmp/access_log vcommon
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/localhost/htdocs/%0/web
VirtualScriptAlias /var/www/localhost/htdocs/%0/web
```

Obviously I've attempted to add

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

to the <Directory/>, but that doesn't help.

Comment: I'm aware this is borderline between the Drupal specific site, and Stackoverflow. I'm posting here, because I'm interested in how this works together with _Drupals_ .htaccess, not _any_ .htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add a slash before index.php to get this working for WordPress. Has to do with VirtualDocumentRoot not setting the DocumentRoot to the same value I guess.

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]`

Answer (score 1):

Might want to checkout http://www.latenightpc.com/blog/archives/2007/09/05/a-couple-ways-to-debug-mod_rewrite